# Fail to install modules for python 3.9.6 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, python-module, python-3.9

I have a problem that when I try to install python 3 modules, using setup.py, I get this messsage

```
python3 /home/pi/Python-3.9.6/setup.py build
running build
running build_ext
INFO: Can't locate Tcl/Tk libs and/or headers
building '_struct' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c _struct.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/_struct.o
gcc: error: _struct.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building 'array' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c arraymodule.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/arraymodule.o
gcc: error: arraymodule.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building '_contextvars' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c _contextvarsmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/_contextvarsmodule.o
gcc: error: _contextvarsmodule.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building 'math' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c mathmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/mathmodule.o -DPy_BUILD_CORE_MODULE
gcc: error: mathmodule.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building 'cmath' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c cmathmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/cmathmodule.o -DPy_BUILD_CORE_MODULE
gcc: error: cmathmodule.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building '_datetime' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c _datetimemodule.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/_datetimemodule.o
gcc: error: _datetimemodule.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building '_zoneinfo' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c _zoneinfo.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/_zoneinfo.o
gcc: error: _zoneinfo.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building '_random' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c _randommodule.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/_randommodule.o -DPy_BUILD_CORE_MODULE
gcc: error: _randommodule.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building '_bisect' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c _bisectmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/_bisectmodule.o
gcc: error: _bisectmodule.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building '_heapq' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c _heapqmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/_heapqmodule.o
gcc: error: _heapqmodule.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building '_pickle' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c _pickle.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/_pickle.o -DPy_BUILD_CORE_MODULE
gcc: error: _pickle.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building '_json' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c _json.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/_json.o -DPy_BUILD_CORE_MODULE
gcc: error: _json.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building '_lsprof' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c _lsprof.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/_lsprof.o
gcc: error: _lsprof.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building 'unicodedata' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c unicodedata.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/unicodedata.o
gcc: error: unicodedata.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building '_opcode' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c _opcode.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/_opcode.o
gcc: error: _opcode.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building '_asyncio' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c _asynciomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/_asynciomodule.o -DPy_BUILD_CORE_MODULE
gcc: error: _asynciomodule.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building '_queue' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c _queuemodule.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/_queuemodule.o
gcc: error: _queuemodule.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building '_statistics' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c _statisticsmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/_statisticsmodule.o
gcc: error: _statisticsmodule.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building 'fcntl' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c fcntlmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/fcntlmodule.o
gcc: error: fcntlmodule.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building 'grp' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c grpmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/grpmodule.o
gcc: error: grpmodule.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building 'spwd' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c spwdmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/spwdmodule.o
gcc: error: spwdmodule.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building 'select' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c selectmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/selectmodule.o
gcc: error: selectmodule.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building 'parser' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c parsermodule.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/parsermodule.o
gcc: error: parsermodule.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building 'mmap' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c mmapmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/mmapmodule.o
gcc: error: mmapmodule.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building 'syslog' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c syslogmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/syslogmodule.o
gcc: error: syslogmodule.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building '_xxsubinterpreters' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c _xxsubinterpretersmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/_xxsubinterpretersmodule.o
gcc: error: _xxsubinterpretersmodule.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building 'audioop' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c audioop.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/audioop.o
gcc: error: audioop.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building '_csv' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c _csv.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/_csv.o
gcc: error: _csv.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building '_posixsubprocess' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c _posixsubprocess.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/_posixsubprocess.o
gcc: error: _posixsubprocess.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building '_testcapi' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c _testcapimodule.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/_testcapimodule.o
gcc: error: _testcapimodule.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building '_testinternalcapi' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c _testinternalcapi.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/_testinternalcapi.o -DPy_BUILD_CORE_MODULE
gcc: error: _testinternalcapi.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building '_testbuffer' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c _testbuffer.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/_testbuffer.o
gcc: error: _testbuffer.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building '_testimportmultiple' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c _testimportmultiple.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/_testimportmultiple.o
gcc: error: _testimportmultiple.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building '_testmultiphase' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c _testmultiphase.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/_testmultiphase.o
gcc: error: _testmultiphase.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building '_xxtestfuzz' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c _xxtestfuzz/_xxtestfuzz.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/_xxtestfuzz/_xxtestfuzz.o
gcc: error: _xxtestfuzz/_xxtestfuzz.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building '_crypt' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c _cryptmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/_cryptmodule.o
gcc: error: _cryptmodule.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building '_socket' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c socketmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/socketmodule.o
gcc: error: socketmodule.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building '_sha256' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c sha256module.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/sha256module.o -DPy_BUILD_CORE_MODULE
gcc: error: sha256module.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building '_sha512' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c sha512module.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/sha512module.o -DPy_BUILD_CORE_MODULE
gcc: error: sha512module.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building '_md5' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c md5module.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/md5module.o
gcc: error: md5module.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building '_sha1' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c sha1module.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/sha1module.o
gcc: error: sha1module.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building '_blake2' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c _blake2/blake2b_impl.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/_blake2/blake2b_impl.o
gcc: error: _blake2/blake2b_impl.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building '_sha3' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c _sha3/sha3module.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/_sha3/sha3module.o
gcc: error: _sha3/sha3module.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building 'termios' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c termios.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/termios.o
gcc: error: termios.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building 'resource' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c resource.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/resource.o
gcc: error: resource.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building 'ossaudiodev' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c ossaudiodev.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/ossaudiodev.o
gcc: error: ossaudiodev.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building 'nis' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c nismodule.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/nismodule.o
gcc: error: nismodule.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building 'zlib' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c zlibmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/zlibmodule.o
gcc: error: zlibmodule.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building 'binascii' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c binascii.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/binascii.o -DUSE_ZLIB_CRC32
gcc: error: binascii.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building 'pyexpat' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DHAVE_EXPAT_CONFIG_H=1 -DXML_POOR_ENTROPY=1 -I/usr/local/lib/python3.9/config-3.9-arm-linux-gnueabihf/Modules/expat -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c expat/xmlparse.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/expat/xmlparse.o -Wno-unreachable-code
gcc: error: expat/xmlparse.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building '_multibytecodec' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c cjkcodecs/multibytecodec.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/cjkcodecs/multibytecodec.o
gcc: error: cjkcodecs/multibytecodec.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building '_codecs_kr' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c cjkcodecs/_codecs_kr.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/cjkcodecs/_codecs_kr.o
gcc: error: cjkcodecs/_codecs_kr.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building '_codecs_jp' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c cjkcodecs/_codecs_jp.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/cjkcodecs/_codecs_jp.o
gcc: error: cjkcodecs/_codecs_jp.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building '_codecs_cn' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c cjkcodecs/_codecs_cn.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/cjkcodecs/_codecs_cn.o
gcc: error: cjkcodecs/_codecs_cn.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building '_codecs_tw' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c cjkcodecs/_codecs_tw.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/cjkcodecs/_codecs_tw.o
gcc: error: cjkcodecs/_codecs_tw.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building '_codecs_hk' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c cjkcodecs/_codecs_hk.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/cjkcodecs/_codecs_hk.o
gcc: error: cjkcodecs/_codecs_hk.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building '_codecs_iso2022' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c cjkcodecs/_codecs_iso2022.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/cjkcodecs/_codecs_iso2022.o
gcc: error: cjkcodecs/_codecs_iso2022.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building '_decimal' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DCONFIG_32=1 -DANSI=1 -I/usr/local/lib/python3.9/config-3.9-arm-linux-gnueabihf/Modules/_decimal/libmpdec -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c _decimal/_decimal.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/_decimal/_decimal.o
gcc: error: _decimal/_decimal.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building '_ctypes_test' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c _ctypes/_ctypes_test.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/_ctypes/_ctypes_test.o
gcc: error: _ctypes/_ctypes_test.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building '_posixshmem' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -IModules/_multiprocessing -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c _multiprocessing/posixshmem.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/_multiprocessing/posixshmem.o
gcc: error: _multiprocessing/posixshmem.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building '_multiprocessing' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -IModules/_multiprocessing -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c _multiprocessing/multiprocessing.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/_multiprocessing/multiprocessing.o
gcc: error: _multiprocessing/multiprocessing.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building '_uuid' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/include/uuid -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c _uuidmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/_uuidmodule.o
gcc: error: _uuidmodule.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building 'xxlimited' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DPy_LIMITED_API=0x03050000 -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c xxlimited.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/xxlimited.o
gcc: error: xxlimited.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
building '_ctypes' extension
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c _ctypes/_ctypes.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.9/_ctypes/_ctypes.o -DPy_BUILD_CORE_MODULE
gcc: error: _ctypes/_ctypes.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

Python build finished successfully!
The necessary bits to build these optional modules were not found:
_bz2                  _curses               _curses_panel      
_dbm                  _elementtree          _gdbm              
_hashlib              _lzma                 _sqlite3           
_ssl                  _tkinter              readline           
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.


The following modules found by detect_modules() in setup.py, have been
built by the Makefile instead, as configured by the Setup files:
_abc                  atexit                pwd                
time                                                           


Failed to build these modules:
_asyncio              _bisect               _blake2            
_codecs_cn            _codecs_hk            _codecs_iso2022    
_codecs_jp            _codecs_kr            _codecs_tw         
_contextvars          _crypt                _csv               
_ctypes               _ctypes_test          _datetime          
_decimal              _heapq                _json              
_lsprof               _md5                  _multibytecodec    
_multiprocessing      _opcode               _pickle            
_posixshmem           _posixsubprocess      _queue             
_random               _sha1                 _sha256            
_sha3                 _sha512               _socket            
_statistics           _struct               _testbuffer        
_testcapi             _testimportmultiple   _testinternalcapi  
_testmultiphase       _uuid                 _xxsubinterpreters 
_xxtestfuzz           _zoneinfo             array              
audioop               binascii              cmath              
fcntl                 grp                   math               
mmap                  nis                   ossaudiodev        
parser                pyexpat               resource           
select                spwd                  syslog             
termios               unicodedata           xxlimited          
zlib                                                           


Could not build the ssl module!
Python requires an OpenSSL 1.0.2 or 1.1 compatible libssl with X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set1_host().
LibreSSL 2.6.4 and earlier do not provide the necessary APIs, https://github.com/libressl-portable/portable/issues/381

running build_scripts
error: file '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/config-3.9-arm-linux-gnueabihf/Tools/scripts/pydoc3' does not exist.
```

As you can see, about 30 modules failed to load, can anyone tell me why? Thank you in advance.

Comment: First, this is not exactly a programming question, so StackOverflow is probably not the ideal place for this. Try something like SuperUser next time. Second, please make yourself familiar with how to format text here. Using a code block for your messages would make reading your message much easier. As for your problem, it looks like you're missing some libraries. You can probably install them using `apt-get install`. Make sure to get the `-dev` versions.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the cause, in `setup.py`:

```
def build_extensions(self):
    self.srcdir = sysconfig.get_config_var('srcdir')
    self.srcdir = os.path.abspath(self.srcdir)

    [SNIP]

    # Fix up the autodetected modules, prefixing all the source files
    # with Modules/.
    moddirlist = [os.path.join(self.srcdir, 'Modules')]
```

It's picking the wrong source directory.

I replaced the second line of the function above with:

```
self.srcdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```